# Rectangle with grid

Tags: html, css

I'm having a bit of difficulty creating a rectangle that looks like this. I'm a novice, any help would be great!

This is what I'm trying to recreate:
[image: Demo]

I know how to make the rectangle, and I'm assuming you would split the rectangle into two sections, where one would use "table" to create the rows for Name, Diagnosis etc.

```css
#box {
  margin-top: 1%;    
  height: 20px;
  width: 562px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 100px;
}

.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.left-half {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
}

.right-half {
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: There are many ways to do it. Using `display: table` would be a good option, the elements will behave as if they were a table. You could also use flex-box or just floating divs. Add your current html code and everything you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Flex grid <3 they are amazing

I have provided you three examples. Rows, columns and an additional example to show more properties of the flex box.

> justify-content and align-items are amazing tools to align things quickly.

## Example:

```css
/*ExamplE box*/

.example {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; /*Direction of flex*/
  justify-content:center; /*horizontally aligns them to center*/
  align-items: center; /*Vertically aligns them to center*/
}

.example__children {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}




/*Column box*/
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.column__children {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}




/*Row box*/
.row {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.row__children {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <div class="example__children"></div>
  <div class="example__children"></div>
  <div class="example__children"></div>
  <div class="example__children"></div>
</div>

<div class="column">
  <div class="column__children"></div>
  <div class="column__children"></div>
  <div class="column__children"></div>
  <div class="column__children"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="row__children"></div>
  <div class="row__children"></div>
  <div class="row__children"></div>
  <div class="row__children"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Harry! This is great! Do you know how to join two of them thought? Similar to the picture I sent above.

Comment: Np :), and yes i have edited the code. You simply float all the parent divs to left(float: left;), which will align them horizontally.

Comment: Thank you so much!